# Url Route issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I installed locally this [project](https://github.com/SleepingOwlAdmin/demo) from github.

In this case one of my many urls looks like: `/admin/companies/` . I am asking myself where the routing part is done. I mean I searched in all of the files after "companies" also in the db and I found nothing!. I believed that I will find in this file `Admin/routes.php`, like:

```
Route::get('companies', ['as' => 'admin.orders', function () {
    $content = 'information here.';
    return AdminSection::view($content, 'Information');
}]);
```

but that's not the case. Please help finding where the routing part is done for `companies`. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the docs to understand how routes in this package work.

> SleepingOwl admin module creates RESTful-style controller for your models.

http://sleeping-owl.github.io/en/Routes/Default_Routes.html

If you want to add custom routes, create them in [app\Admin\bootstrap.php](https://github.com/SleepingOwlAdmin/demo/blob/master/app/Admin/bootstrap.php) file.

> You can register your own routes in bootstrap.php file within bootstrapDirectory (default is app/admin/bootstrap.php).

http://sleeping-owl.github.io/en/Routes/Custom_Routes.html

Comment: I tried to set my own route like: Orders::get('my-url', function ()
{
    return Orders::view('my page content');
});  but i got a blank page. PS. So much details in the docs :|